# Confusion regarding manuscript status in IOP's article tracking system and ScholarOne Manuscript System

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission, publishers

I had submitted a manuscript in an IOP journal a month back. In the IOP's article tracking system, the status changed from "*1st reviewer agreed to report*" to "*Editorial Assessment*" instead of "*All reviewer reports received*". However, in the ScholarOne Manuscript System, the status changed from "*Awaiting Referee Reports*" to "*Awaiting Decision*". What should be the interpretation of the current status of the manuscript?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The IOP's tracking system shows that it has gone back to the editorial office for a check whether the submission is complete and meets the scope and quality criteria of the journal. I am not sure if there is a bug in the tracking system. I would have expected "Revision: All reviewer reports received" since the previous status was "1st reviewer agreed to report".

Comment: Have you checked the answer to the question I have linked? Does it answer your question? Can you identify where your manuscript is on that flowchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Awaiting decision” is not incompatible with “All reviewer report received” or “Editorial Assessment”.  It means the editor, an associate editor or a handling editor will have a look and make a decision.

Remember that referees can only *recommend* a course of action: it is the journal through its editor or delegates that takes the decision to publish or not, usually based on the reports.

In particular if the review or reviews are inconclusive, the editor may decide to send to another reviewer.